# How does an iterator object keep track of its position in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to lear generators but before going into that I want to know how/why this works

```
function makeIterator(array){
    var nextIndex = 0;    
    return {
       next: function(){
           return nextIndex++
       }
    }
}
var it = makeIterator([1,2,3,4]);
```

Why is it that `it.next()` return `1` and another `it.next()` returns `2`. How does it know?

Is there a way to see how it works behind the scenes?

Comment: Note that the first call to `it.next()` results in 0, not 1, and that those numbers are unrelated to the contents of the array you've passed in.

Comment: This is related to closures, you should read this post, it's GREAT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work it changed the way I look at javascript forever.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator is an object with state. In your case, the state is the private `nextIndex` closure variable, that's how it keeps track.

There's no magic going on behind the scenes here, if you didn't have that variable, you'd get an error.